# DataFrame .head() doesn't work when calling it from a function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, ipython, jupyter-notebook

When calling this function in Jupyter's Notebook, it prints nothing:

```
def printess(request):
        table_AltModels[request].head(10)
```

where in this code table_AltModels[request] is a valid dataframe.

I would like my function to show the dataframe in a table like here:
[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CE3qj.png)

Thanks

Comment: You're missing `return` ?

Comment: so maybe need `return table_AltModels[request].head(10)`

Comment: But I would like to print out of the function

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Either use a return or a print

```
return table_AltModels[request].head(10)
```

or

```
print table_AltModels[request].head(10)
```

or

```
from IPython.display import display
display(table_AltModels[request].head(10))
```

Comment: return statement will print out of the function?
The print option doesn't show the dataframe beautifuly in a table

Comment: No, return will not do so. If you want to display it beautifully use display. I will edit my response for that.